# When I click on an image, how can I drop all the other images except the image I click on?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on an image, I want to use the jquery "drop" event top drop all images except the one I just clicked on. And when I click on it again, I want all the images to appear. How exactly do I do that?

```
<script>        
     $("div#img1" ).click(function() {
      $( "div#img2, div#img3, div#img4" ).toggle( "drop" );
    });
    </script>
```

So additionally, I am also making a div and a table fade in when I click on the image. Not sure though if I'm doing too many actions now.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
$("div#img1").click(function() {
  $("div#description1, table#playlist1").fadeToggle('slow');
});
```

});

Comment: add a common class to all images and use `$('.common').not($(this)).toggle('drop')` Refer this fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/xxp64us7/

Comment: Thank you! Didn't realize that's how I would write it!